# How to edit Mesh Attributes?

Tags: mesh, geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

How do I use the "Attributes" that I can create in a mesh object?

I'm able to create an attribute that is associated with a mesh, and I can assign it to a domain (i.e. vertex, Face, etc).  It shows up in the spreadsheet viewer.  But how do I change the values for each vertex?  I need to be able to assign the values, otherwise this is useless to me.  It's just a bunch of zeroes.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable MeasureIt and vertex indices visibility:

[image]

Add a new object, name it `attribute setter`, and add a new geonodes setup to it. Drag the object of choice from outliner to the node tree:

[image]

And apply this geonodes modifier.

> If you want to edit attributes of vertices, you can skip the above step and just duplicate `my object` and rename it to `attribute setter`

Add shape keys, set the 2nd shape key to have full effect:

[image]

Now you can use the base shape key to easily find and select a vertex you want to modify, then move to the other shape key and assign the Vector values as vertex location:

[image]

Finally you can go back to your object `my object`, and add a geonodes setup transferring that data:

[image]

You can apply that geonodes modifier, or leave it dynamically linking the data.

Comment:  ...a little unwieldy, but an interesting approach

Comment: @quellenform this seems like the most reasonable [storage of data](https://youtu.be/adhTmwYwOiA?t=700) - obviously editing is unwieldy for multiple vertices and for that I'd use Python… You could avoid using shape keys and just store as 3 vertex groups, but problem is then it becomes incompatible with the workflow in the video…

Comment: @quellenform also, You're from Europe, it's time to sleep 

Comment: a very hacky approach which I will almost certainly forget by the next time I need this - but very smart.  It solved my immediate problem, thank you.  In my case, I didn't need to re-generate the mesh using your first set of geo-nodes and the shape-key business, because my mesh was static.  But for a mesh that may change, I can see the utility.  In my case, I just duplicated the object and started moving vertices.  Thank you!

Comment: @rothloup I disagree about it being hacky [I'm not getting emotional, just arguing]: as I linked [above](https://youtu.be/adhTmwYwOiA?t=700) this is not a new technique, in fact I also mentioned using separate geometry to store data in this [thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249580/60486) – it's just a solution that comes naturally. Shape keys are added so you can easily find vertices, especially those very far from origin or those that overlap with other vertices.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady:  I get it, and I didn't mean it disrespectfully.  I used the term because something that is not meant to do a thing (store attribute data) is being used to do that thing, and it "arises naturally" only because the natural approach (i.e. to use a vector attribute in the vertex domain, as implied by my original question) doesn't work.  If it did, I can't imagine why anyone would have had to come up with this method.  Nonetheless, I thank you, and I'm using your method now.

Answer (score 4):

The [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#custom-attributes) says: *"Vertex groups, UV maps and Color Attributes are available as attributes in geometry nodes."*

This means: Currently you can only process custom color attributes in geometry nodes.

---

Just create a new attribute and select the data type *Byte color*.

You can then change these attributes in the *Vertex Paint* mode by coloring the vertices:

[image]

The advantage of a color, however, is that it also consists of four float values (*RGBA*), which can be handy depending on the application:

[image]

Comment: ok, so this gets me half of what I need.  I can now influence the values.  But two issues:  1)  I can't set the values to what I want.  If I set my brush to 100%, no falloff, Mix mode, and RGB = [0.5, 1, 0] the target vertex gets a value of [0.212, 1, 0].  I think this has to do with RGB encoding but I don't know.  How do I just set the number to what I want?  and 2)  I really want to use a vector, not RGB, so I can use values >1.

Comment: @rothloup Yes, this is actually related to the color processing mode. But unfortunately there is (currently) no other answer, because with individual attributes only color values in combination with *Geometry Nodes* are possible. The only way I know is to set attributes with Python: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266991

Answer (score 2):

## New proper solution since Blender 3.5

This is the way now:

Edit Mode > Mesh > Set Attribute

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/set_attribute.html