# Animating custom attributes with python

Tags: python, custom-attributes, custom-properties

I'm looking for a way to animate custom Blender attributes. Let's say we have an attribute created using the solution from this post: [Manually setting custom attributes per edge / vertex / etc](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/266991/manually-setting-custom-attributes-per-edge-vertex-etc)

```
import bpy

mesh = bpy.context.collection.objects["Cube"].data
attribute = mesh.attributes.new(name="new attribute", type="FLOAT", domain="POINT")
attribute_values = [i for i in range(len(mesh.vertices))]
attribute.data.foreach_set("value", attribute_values)
```

Now, when I'm trying to add animation using `attribute.keyframe_insert()`, I'm facing a problem. What should be entered into the `data_path` argument? I've tried entering `"value"` or the output of `dir(attribute)` without success.

Comment: Can you set keyframes for attributes manually (through the interface)? I thought we can only keyframe properties.